# Split XML per group of related nodes

Tags: xml

CLI tools like csplit allow us to split XML files based on a certain element. I want to split XML files per group. For instance:

```
<prices>
  <price>
    <code>A123</code>
    <discount>123</discount>
  </price>
  <price>
    <code>A123</code>
    <discount>123</discount>
  </price>
  <price>
    <code>B456</code>
    <discount>123</discount>
  </price>
</prices>
```

needs to be splitted to one file with:

```
<price>
    <code>A123</code>
    <discount>123</discount>
</price>
<price>
    <code>A123</code>
    <discount>123</discount>
</price>
```

and another file with:

```
<price>
    <code>B456</code>
    <discount>123</discount>
</price>
```

We can achieve this by using a streaming XML parser and comparing the value of the code-element with the previous one and generate new XML files if they are not equal. However there must be a more efficient way by using a combination of CLI tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML):

```
open file.xml ;
$h := hash code /prices/price ;
for $code in { keys %$h } {
    $d := create prices ;
    xcp xsh:lookup('h', $code) into $d/prices ;
    save :f concat($code, '.xml') $d ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I see that the last release was in 2008 and it won't even compile.

Comment: I released it on Aug 26 this year. Did you click the correct link?